# NVIDIA Driver Crashing on Custom-Built Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got a custom-built PC with these specs:

- [Fractal Design Define R3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811352013)
- [ASUS P8Z77-V motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z77V/)
- Intel Core i7-2700k with [Thermalright HR-02 Macho Cooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005ERSN7G)
- [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130664) with [Arctic Cooling Accelero Twin Turbo II Cooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FYCFG8)
- Crucial M4 128 GB SSD
- 1 TB Hitachi HDD
- [G.SKILL Ares Series 2x8 GB RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231558) (x2)
- [SeaSonic 520W PSU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151094)
- Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 (x64)
- NVIDIA driver version 301.42

Upon building the PC, I overclocked the CPU (but never the GPU), and there were no problems for 1-2 months. Then I started getting crashes with one of these errors when doing anything that's computationally or graphically intensive:

[image: NVIDIA Crash Dialog: Error code 3]

[image: NVIDIA Crash Dialog: Error code 7]

I un-overclocked the CPU, but that hasn't fixed anything.

This is what the inside of my case looks like:

[image: Inside of Case]

I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this problem. I did get some of the thermal paste on the graphics card when installing the aftermarket cooler, but there were no issues for a month or two.

### Update

I did a clean install and the issue persisted - looks like it's a hardware issue. I will try removing/cleaning/reseating all the parts.

### Update #2

I'm having similar issues in Ubuntu 12.04, so it's almost definitely hardware related, and not a driver bug.

### Update #3

There were no crashes after removing the NVIDIA graphics card and using Intel on-board graphics.

Comment: Ok 1. did you try updating the drivers? Weird things happen, update drivers or reinstall...2. where did you get thermal grease on? was it on the contacts for the pci slot?

Comment: 301.42 is the latest version, although I can try reinstalling it. I got the thermal paste on the surface of the graphics card, nowhere near the PCI slot contacts. Some just dripped onto the card, off the flat surfaces on which I was putting it and then gluing the heatsinks to.

Comment: I really didn't think it would be from the grease. Try reinstalling first. Gotta trouble shoot this thing. If your still having issues it may be a faulty card i had a amd card run for about a month then out of no where random crashes...it was a faulty card. also curious how many watts is your psu?

Comment: OK, I'll try reinstalling the driver. My PSU does 520 W.

Comment: I just reinstalled the driver. I removed everything I could with Add/Remove Programs, and then purged the rest with [Driver Fusion](http://treexy.com/products/driver-fusion). Even after reinstalling with a redownloaded copy of the latest version (301.42), there are errors when I try to run graphically intensive software. The error this time was a little different: see it [here](http://i.imgur.com/8lM2m.png)

Comment: I Googled the new error and tried modifying the `TdrDelay` registry key as suggested, but that did nothing except increase the amount of time it was frozen before it crashed.

Comment: It looks like it's a hardware issue. I'll try removing/reseating all the components.

Comment: How extensive was your overclocking? It looks like your motherboard has on-board graphics. What if you use the on-board graphics instead of your card, do similar crashes happen? Did you do anything else that might have triggered this? A BIOS setting perhaps. Also, is it always exactly that specific error, or are there other errors happening as well?

Comment: What were your temperatures and vcore when overclocked? Do you know if you were over the Tcase safe temperature or within 10 degrees of the TJ max? Did you keep track of any/how much throttling was occurring on the processor? Was this a strait overclock or an offset overclock? Also did you pay attention to your load line calibration and Voltage regulation module tempertures? Even a mild OC can cause extreme heat on the VRM depending on what LLC is set to.

Comment: In fact when I look at your picture I can't even see the VRM heat sync. It's underneath the metal plate from the CPU heat sync.

Comment: Did you get the error before overclocking? (or did you overclock before installing Windows?)

Comment: Try using [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to monitor your graphics card temperature while under load, note that you have an option to continue monitoring temperatures while in a game on the Sensors page.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I overclocked the CPU to about 4.2 GHz, but I don't believe that was the cause - I've run intensive CPU-bound processes for a week at a time without any issues. The crash _only_ occurs when the GPU is taxed. Using the on-board graphics works fine (no crashes, although it is more sluggish, as expected). When I started experiencing the crashes, I hadn't touched the BIOS in weeks. There are only two errors I'm seeing, the code 3 and the code 7.

Comment: @ForceFlow: I got the error a few months after overclocking, which I did after installing Windows and setting everything up.

Comment: @Mokubai: According to GPU-Z, the crashes occur at around 39-40 C. The crashes are not a result of a game, so I was able to watch the GPU-Z window at the same time.

Comment: Try the graphics card with a different PC...to check if the problem is with card itself..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overclocking for long periods can be very harmful in case of temperature highs, even short ones.
You might have cooked up some part of the motherboard or some circuit inside that ultra-complex CPU (1.16 billion transistors).

The Core i7-2700k has the clock speed of 3.5 GHz, but thanks to
the Intel Turbo Boost Technology it can achieve the max turbo frequency of 3.9 GHz,
stopping turbo mode automatically when the temperature exceeds its limits.
Over-clocking is uncalled for when Turbo Boost can do a much safer job.

In addition, the 2700's are actually handicapped Xeons. When Intel makes a CPU by etching billions of transistors onto a silicon wafer it is inevitable that some may fail.
They get sorted out by testing, with the most perfect put in the Xeon bin for mission-critical purposes.
The deciding criteria on whether a chip is classified as Xeon, i7, i5 or i3,
is both the cache size and the highest electrical frequency it can tolerate.

Your 2700 is an i7, meaning that 100% of its cache (8MB) formed properly compared to 80% in an i5 (6MB).
Its core and graphics clock can reliably cycle 100MHz and 250MHz higher then an i5 respectively, but less than a Xeon.
This means that for your 2700, as the cache memory has fully passed the test,
it is on electrical frequency tolerance that your I7 has failed to achieve the highest grade.

I hope you have been keeping an eye on the running temperature and have installed
some software to alert you in case of a problem, such as [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php),
and have verified that all the S.M.A.R.T sensors were functional
and have tested your hardware with IntelBurnTest.

To check out the hardware, I suggest replacing parts, starting with the CPU, then memory and so on. Test products that work by putting stress on the CPU and memory can be useful,
but most will only detect hard failures.

[EDIT]

Some things to try in software :

In NVIDIA Control Panel --> Manage 3D Settings --> Global Settings, switch "Power Management Mode" to "Prefer Maximum Performance" rather than the default "Adaptive" setting.

Also about the OpenGL message "lost connection": You can find more information in this Microsoft page: [Timeout Detection and Recovery of GPUs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx).
In short, the workload sent to the Graphics Card was greater than what the graphics card can process in the normal timeout of two seconds.

Two possible solutions to try would be:

1. Reduce the graphics workload if possible, such as rendering to a lower resolution or with less detail.
2. Increase the timeout to allow more time to complete the really tough rendering parts. Microsoft provides the information on how to modify the registry to achieve this (although it accepts no responsibility for it).

Comment: Typical temperatures in SpeedFan hover [around  30-40C](http://i.imgur.com/YWi6p.png). I haven't used IntelBurn Test, but after overclocking the CPU, I tested stability using Prime95. Note that there are no stability issues when running CPU-bound processes - I can run them for days with no issues.

Comment: I added some more ideas above. Sorry about my tirade above, but overclocking such a beautiful CPU gets me going this way.

Comment: As I noted above, I already tried modifying the registry by adding the `TdrDelay` key. The only difference it made was that the machine froze up for a longer period of time before crashing. Also, I tried removing the NVIDIA card and ran the same GPU-intensive software with just onboard graphics. It was of course much more sluggish, but I encountered no more crashes. I'll try your other suggestions next.

Comment: I tried changing the Power Management Mode to "Prefer Maximum Performance", but that didn't have any appreciable effect. I also tried resizing the window so that the rendering would be over a small portion of the screen, but that just meant more time before the crash occurred (10 seconds instead of 3 seconds).

Comment: Have you tried another video card?

Comment: Just tried an ATI Radeon HD 4350. Again, not so fast, but it never crashed.

Comment: This probably means that the nvidia is bad. Without getting into the question whether overclocking was responsible for it or not, and if the card is still under warranty, try to exchange it. If this happens with another identical card than it is the nvidia driver that doesn't get along with your setup (unlikely as it worked ok for 2 months). If it never happens again, you solved your problem (but don't overclock again since this might have overtaxed the nvidia). Question: you are sure you haven't added something that placed additional burden on the PSU?

Comment: ... another possibility is that the problem dates to the time that the video driver was updated by Windows. If that's the case, you may have to rollback this update.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could overclocking the CPU cause GPU problems? I will first try installing older versions of the driver to see if that helps, although the fact that I saw the same issue in Ubuntu (which has a separately developed driver, even though it is also proprietary and from NVIDIA) means that I'm not too hopeful. I'm sure that I haven't added anything to place additional burden on the PSU. I only have 1 SSD & 1 HDD, no optical drives, only that 1 graphics card, no other PCI/PCIe cards, and no extra fans (other than those that came with the case).

Comment: From [the driver release dates on the NVIDIA website](http://i.imgur.com/LOUnd.png), it looks like I've been using the latest stable version of the driver ever since building the PC, so I don't think it was an driver update issue. In any case, I tried the latest beta version of the driver, and saw the same results.

Comment: I have been trying to cover all bases, software and hardware, but it does look more like hardware. I can only theorize that an overclocked CPU might have driven harder the video card, thus provoking an existing fault. If that's the case, you might actually be lucky that it has arrived during warranty.

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and RMA it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

**Fan speed control**: Does the aftermarket cooler have a smaller fan that is supposed to turn faster (as compared to stock one)? Or it could just be a case of the default graphics driver settings trying to keep lower fan speed to limit the noise. Try using a program that allows you to change fan speed, and set it to much higher value.

**Power input**: Check if the graphics card is supplied power from a rail that also splits a lot to supply the hard disk etc. Unlikely to be a cause, but swapping around the rails used is easy to try.

**Thermal paste**: This may have been applied unevenly, and/or the layer was too thick and flaked off over time. Unfortunately, this isn't something you can test; only re-attach the cooler if you suspect this issue.

**Rear case fan**: Is this working well in drawing out the heat from the cpu? If not, the hot air from CPU cooler may be overloading the graphics cooler right next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem on a Latitude e6530 laptop with NVS 5200M Nvidia video card + latest driver. To solve the issue, I had to enter the BIOS and set the Video's "Optimus" checkbox ON.

Comment: Explaining what this option is and how it can affect video performance takes an answer from *"This worked for me"* to *"This should fix your problem because..."*. Try to thoroughly provide information when giving an answer. It can greatly help future users that might stumble on to it.